# malloc(): corrupted top size Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Tags: c++

please tell me why memory is not allocated in the line `CLNAME* tmp=new CLNAME[this->Capacity_Ram];` the second day I'm looking for a problem, I can not understand what the problem is. The task is to write self-written vectors
Code:
header:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <memory.h>

using namespace std;

template <class CLNAME>
class MyVector{
protected:
        CLNAME* Array;
        int Size_Ram = 0;
        int Capacity_Ram = 5;
public:
        MyVector();
        MyVector(const MyVector<CLNAME> &other);
        int Capacity();
        int Size();
        void PushBack(CLNAME item);

};
#include "MyVector.ipp"
```

ipp:

```
//Конструкторы
template <class CLNAME>
MyVector<CLNAME>::MyVector() {
    this->Array = new CLNAME[this->Capacity_Ram];
}
template <class CLNAME>
MyVector<CLNAME>::MyVector(const MyVector<CLNAME> &other) {
    this->Capacity_Ram=other.Capacity_Ram;
    this->Size_Ram=other.Size_Ram;
    Array = new CLNAME[other.Capacity_Ram];
    for (int i=0;i<other.Size_Ram;i++){
        this->Array[i]=other.Array[i];
    }
}


//Методы
template <class CLNAME>
int MyVector<CLNAME>::Capacity(){
    return(this->Capacity_Ram);
};
template <class CLNAME>
int MyVector<CLNAME>::Size(){
    return(this->Size_Ram);
};
template <class CLNAME>
void MyVector<CLNAME>::PushBack(CLNAME item) {
    if (this->Size_Ram==0){
        Array = new CLNAME[this->Capacity_Ram];
        this->Capacity_Ram=Capacity_Ram*2;
    }
    if(Size_Ram==Capacity_Ram){
        this->Capacity_Ram=Capacity_Ram*2;
        CLNAME* tmp=new CLNAME[this->Capacity_Ram];
        for (int i=0;i<Size_Ram;i++){
            tmp[i]=Array[i];
        }
        delete [] Array;
        Array = tmp;
    }
    Array[Size_Ram]=item;
    Size_Ram+=1;
}





//template <class CLNAME>
//MyVector<CLNAME> MyVector<CLNAME>::operator=(MyVector<CLNAME> other) {
    //if (*this == other){
        //return *this
    //}
    //this->Size_Ram=other.Size;
    //this->Capacity_Ram=other.Capacity;
    //this->Array=other.Array;

//};
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyVector.h"

int main() {
    MyVector<int> vectors;
    int a=65;
    cout<<vectors.Capacity()<<endl;
    cout<<vectors.Size()<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
        vectors.PushBack(i);
    }
    cout<<vectors.Size()<<endl;
    cout<<vectors.Capacity()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Note: `Array = new CLNAME[this->Capacity_Ram];` in `PushBack` if `Size_ram == 0` leaks memory, since that chunk is already allocated in the constructor, and never freed. Also the array goes out of scope but is never freed as no destructor is present

Comment: The problem with memory corruption errors is the place you see the error is after the memory has already been corrupted. Chances are you're writing outside the bounds of an allocated block somewhere. Address sanitizer can help with this: https://godbolt.org/z/bcsT8en67 Take a look at the order you assign the capacity and allocate memory when the size is 0 in `PushBack`.

Comment: Take a look at `if (this->Size_Ram==0)`.  You allocate 5 elements, but then store 10 as its supposed capacity.  Pushing the sixth element writes past the end of your 5-element array.

Comment: Point is kinda moot though. As @Lala5th points out above, that whole `if` is unnecessary.

Comment: Unrelated: To complete [the Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) `MyVector` needs an assignment operator.

Comment: Possibly you'd want to implement move semantics as well, in addition to the Rule of Three

Comment: @user4581301 and a destructor

Comment: Holy <expletive deleted>. Didn't even see that the destructor was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MyVector<CLNAME>::PushBack`

```
if (this->Size_Ram==0){
    Array = new CLNAME[this->Capacity_Ram]; // already done in constructor, leaks.
                                            // sets capacity of 5 
    this->Capacity_Ram=Capacity_Ram*2;      // advertises a capacity of 10, not 5.
}
```

makes 2 mistakes. 1) storage was already allocated in the constructor so this leaks the constructor's allocation and is unnecessary. 2) `Array = new CLNAME[this->Capacity_Ram];` asks for an array of `Capacity_Ram` elements and then resets the capacity to `Capacity_Ram=Capacity_Ram*2;` ruining  the `if(Size_Ram==Capacity_Ram)` capacity tests later in the program and allowing out-of-bounds accesses.

Solution: Remove the entire first `if` and block. The constructor did this already.

Side note: This class needs an assignment operator and a destructor to go along with the copy constructor.